# Get third party application (Sleep as Android) data from Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm curently trying to get [Sleep as Android](http://sleep.urbandroid.org/) data from Google Fit in my own android application. I read from a post that Sleep as Android data are stored in Google Fit and any 3rd party app can view them. To achieve that, I use History sessions. This is the sample code for reading sleep data:

```
public static DataReadRequest queryFitnessData() {
    // [START build_read_data_request]
    // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
    // [END build_read_data_request]

    return readRequest;
}
```

And to execute that query:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();
DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(
        mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
printData(dataReadResult);
```

My guess is that I'm missing something. I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780050/how-to-get-sleep-data-from-google-fit) post on the same topic but no success until now.

**[QUESTION]**

How can I get recorded Fitness Data for sleep activities from Google Fit?

**[EDIT]**

This is a screenshot of Sleep as Android data in Google Fit's timeline

[image: Google Fit Sleep data]

Comment: Are you syncing the data from "Sleep as Android " with "Google Fit Platform". Can you install the [Google Fit app From Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness) and see whether you can see the sleep data getting reflected in "Google Fit" app

Comment: Yes it's already the case. Let me update my post by adding a screenshot of the data from Sleep as Android into Google Fit. But how can I get the those data programmatically?

Comment: Can you paste the ouput you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it. Thanks to Martin Stava from Urbandroid Team.

```
final SessionReadRequest.Builder sessionBuilder = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()

        .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
        .readSessionsFromAllApps()
        .enableServerQueries();

final SessionReadRequest readRequest = sessionBuilder.build();

// Invoke the Sessions API to fetch the session with the query and wait for the result
// of the read request.
SessionReadResult sessionReadResult = SessionsApi.readSession(apiClient, readRequest).await(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Status status = sessionReadResult.getStatus();
```

Comment: I can't find any information about the response you get with this code. Do you get the information in the same format as [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list)?

Comment: any idea about fetch sleep hours from  google fit ?