# Get data sleep from google fit

Tags: android, sleep, google-fit

I need help from read sleep data from google fit..

I have this method, but not work

```
private void accessGoogleFit(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
    cal.setTime(date);

    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    //SessionReadRequest sessionReadRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder().read(DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY).setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

    DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder().read(DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY).setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).readData(dataReadRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {

            List<DataSet> dataSets = dataReadResponse.getDataSets();
            for(DataSet dataSet: dataSets){
                for(Field field: dataSet.getDataType().getFields()){
                    if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(FitnessActivities.SLEEP)){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ENCONTRADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Does someone have an example that works to read the sleep data?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `startTime` and `endTime` and follow the code implemented in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780050/how-to-get-sleep-data-from-google-fit). There's also a complete sleep-history sample for Fit API in this [github post](https://github.com/aekanman/sleep-history) as well.